# Lagrangian densities, Lie Groups and Lie Algebras

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

I'm quite new to Physics and I was having a look for the first time to the Standard model. I'm not sure if the mechanism that I'm describing is directly from Weyl or from others but what I found quite interesting was this:

1- We have a ***Lagrangian Density*** which has a global symmetry expressed by a **Lie Group** $G$ (let's think about a Lie Group such as $SU(2)$, $U(1)$, $SU(3)$ etc...);

2- I try to construct a Lagrangian Density which has the same symmetry but locally and not globally;

3- To do so I introduce an ***affine connection***;

4- I replace all the derivatives in the Lagrangian Density with the ***Covariant derivatives***;

5- I add an "*ad hoc*" term to the original Lagrangian  a term that directly involves this connection in the Lagrangian Density;

6- with these manipulations I've done (with some effort and some variants from group to group) the Lagrangian density is now ***locally invariant*** for the Lie Group I was starting with.

From this point on the **Standard Model** follows interpreting the proprieties of this Lagrangian. Now, the "*magical*" part that is interesting me is something that can very may well be evident to an expert of Riemannian Geometry.

**My question is**: why that doing such a construction the structure constant of the Lie Algebra corresponding to the original Lie Group appear in the Curvature Tensor related to the affine connection I introduced? Does this depends to the specific form of the Lagrangian or is something which express some deeper geometrical fact that I'm missing?